# How do i fill in an input field with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate updating price of items from an online shop.
So the logic is, you first log in then you search for an item using the item's article.
But I cant seem to access the input field.

i got this error message:
"stale element reference: element is not attached to the page documentraise exception_class"

P.S. I am pretty new at this. started yesterday.

SO this is what i did

```
# find search input field and insert item's article as well
search_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='Умный поиск по названию, артикулу, свойству, производителю'].MuiInputBase-input.MuiInputBase-inputAdornedStart")


#enter the search query into the input field
search_input.send_keys(item)
```

````
<div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInputBase-adornedStart">
    <div class="MuiInputAdornment-root MuiInputAdornment-positionStart"></div>
    <input placeholder="Умный поиск по названию, артикулу, свойству, производителю" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInputBase-inputAdornedStart" value="">
</div>```
````

Comment: You need to edit your question and add the relevant error message into the question itself so readers don't have to scan all comments, etc. to get all the relevant info on the question.

Comment: I would not use `placeholder` as part of the locator because I don't know how it might change based on actions on the page. I would change it to `input.MuiInputBase-input.MuiInputBase-inputAdornedStart` and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @JeffC Thank you all for the recommendation. However, It nothing seems to work. So frustrating. Any more ideas? This is the website, in case anyone is curious https://www.etm.ru/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since now you've provided the URL, here I'm sharing the code snippet. And it is working as I replied in the previous answer.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "https://www.etm.ru/"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

search_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input.MuiInputBase-input.MuiInputBase-inputAdornedStart')
search_input.send_keys("hello")
search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# wait here, so that you can see it working
time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, it might work

```
search_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInputBase-inputAdornedStart"]')
search_input.send_keys(item)
```

or

```
search_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input.MuiInputBase-input.MuiInputBase-inputAdornedStart')
search_input.send_keys(item)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but still doesn't work

Comment: I just tried since you now provided the URL, and it's working fine. I've added the code snippet, please check